# Email validation with validator.js doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

I am trying to validate email input with `validator.js`. This works, but there is a case that it doesn't validate properly.

> example@gmail.commmmmmm

I would like to sort this kind of addresses as not valid. I have already tried to use `domain_specific_validation: true`, but this didn't work.

Is there any solution for this problem?

P.S. I don't want to use a regular expression.

Comment: _I don't want to use regExp_...Are you sure the plugin you are using is not using any?

Comment: I know that this package uses regExp , i just want to validate email with this package , not to write regExp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to validator.js codebase, [it only checks if top level domain (tld) matches the specific regexp](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js/blob/master/lib/isFQDN.js#L40). And as [tld list can always be extended via new registered items](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/tlds-2012-02-25-en), this seems to be correct solution. So, `commmmmmm` is something that **might be** a tld, and that's why validation returns true.

Other solution might be to check if tld is in [registered tld list](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db), you can use [tld-list npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tld-list) for that:

```
const tldList = require('tld-list');
tldList.includes('example@gmail.commmmmmm'.split('.').pop());
```

But this solution requires constantly update this package, to be able to track new tld's as well.

There is also a [validate-tld](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validate-tld) package which does request to the registration service to check if tld is valid:

```
var validateTld = require("validate-tld")
new validateTld().validate('commmm').then( console.log )
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot . Now its clear to me the problem and solutions.